# query the collation name refer to the specific lanuage?

Tags: postgresql

```
   CREATE TABLE collate_test2 (
       a int,
       b text COLLATE "sv-x-icu"
   );
```

what is "sv" mean? I can guess "en" refer to english.
Or How can I query the sv refer to which language.

I already did

```
SELECT * FROM pg_collation where collname ilike '%icu%';
```

there is no an column refer to the language specification.

I also checked https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/collation/api.html#references

Comment: The `sv` is part of the [locale](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/locale) of the ICU definition and specifies the [ISO language code](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/)

Comment: You shouldn't check `collname` but `collcollate` as the name can be anything: `CREATE COLLATION "My Fancy Collation" (provider = icu, locale = 'sv-x-icu')` - then the `create table` would show `b text collate "My Fancy Collation"`

Answer (score 0):

`sv-SE` is locale to Swedish (sv) as spoken in Sweden (SE) (for locale you can check [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html) FAQ). Also I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26253271/19017297) about the difference between **sv** and **sv-SE** for different ISO standards.

`-x-ICU` is an International Components for Unicode (more info [here](https://icu.unicode.org/home), and here is the [reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#id-1.6.10.4.5.6.5) for ICU in PG SQL - 24.2.2.2.2. ICU Collations);

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT collname, collversion  FROM pg_collation where collname ilike '%icu%' and  collname ilike '%zh%';
```

return

```
     collname     | collversion
------------------+-------------
 zh-x-icu         | 153.14.36.8
 zh-Hans-x-icu    | 153.14.36.8
 zh-Hans-CN-x-icu | 153.14.36.8
 zh-Hans-HK-x-icu | 153.14.36.8
 zh-Hans-MO-x-icu | 153.14.36.8
 zh-Hans-SG-x-icu | 153.14.36.8
 zh-Hant-x-icu    | 153.14.36.8
 zh-Hant-HK-x-icu | 153.14.36.8
 zh-Hant-MO-x-icu | 153.14.36.8
 zh-Hant-TW-x-icu | 153.14.36.8
```

**zh** refer to language code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

**Hant** refer to script code: https://www.unicode.org/iso15924/iso15924-codes.html

**CN** refer to country code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes